# How to set NAND constraint with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two date columns `refused_at` and `requested_at` in a table `foo`, both dates can be `NULL`, only one can be filled, both cannot be filled at the same time.

So, I need to add a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`, what should I use for `NAND` operator ?

It should probably look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_status
  CHECK ((refused_at IS NULL) <> (requested_at IS NULL));
```

but `<>` seems to be an `XOR` test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` is not an "xor" - you just compare two boolean values, e.g. `true <> false` or `true <> true`.

You can express this with boolean logic, but using Postgres' `num_nonnulls()` function makes this a lot easier.

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_status
  CHECK (num_nonnulls(refused_at, requested_at) <= 1);
```

This will allow zero "non nulls" (meaning both are null) or at least one.